# How can I read from stdin with this specific command?

Tags: c, bash, unix, command-line

I'm very new to C and I like to know what my program needs so it is able to read from a given test.stdin file, when this command is written to the console:

```
cat test.stdin | ./myprogram | tee myoutput.stdout
```

?

So I guess the test.stdin is some file on the computer which feeds my program with data/input, then my program is doing something with that data and writes the result into the file myoutput.stdout which is also somewhere on my computer.

What do I need in my program so the command above is working? I need to do some calculations with the data in stdin, but I don't know how to begin, how to read like that and make the command work for my program.

Comment: stdin is stdin. Nothing special should be done and simply read from stdin as usual.

Comment: @MikeCAT I've read that it is possible to read from stdin using the fopen function, is that correct here? If yes, I wouldn't know what the parameters of this function need to be so the command above would work. I think something like fopen(somestdin, "r"); will fail because my program will not know what somestdin is supposed to be?

Comment: `"/dev/stdin"` may work if it is supported in your system, but you need not use that and should simply read from the standard input.

Comment: When you're using pipes, normal reading from `stdin` will read from the pipe. You can use the normal functions like `scanf` or `fgets` as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, reading from "standard input", or `stdin`, is the default.  It's the easiest thing there is.  You don't have to explicitly open anything; `stdin` is always opened for you (along with `stdout` and `stderr`) before your `main` function even gets called.

You can read from `stdin` with a variety of standard library functions.  The most common are `getchar` and `scanf`.  And, to repeat: you can just start calling them, on the first line of `main`, if you like.  They work right away; there are no setup steps required.

`getchar` reads one character.
`scanf` reads "formatted input", although this function is full of problems and gotchas, to the point that it's almost not worth using.

To read one line from `stdin`, the function used to be `gets`, although it had a fatal problem and has been removed from the language.  Today, to read one line from `stdin`, one way to do it is with the `fgets` function, which can actually read lines from any stream, so you have to explicitly pass it `stdin` as its `fp` argument.

Answer (score 1):

**stdout**(Standard output) is a place to which a program can send
information (e.g., text). The program never knows where the information
it sends to standard output is going. The information can go to a
printer, an ordinary file, or the terminal(screen). By default the shell
directs standard output from a command to terminal(screen) and describes
how you can cause the shell to redirect this output to another file.

**stdin**(Standard input) is a place a program gets information from; by
default, the shell directs standard input from the keyboard.
As with standard output, the program never “knows” where the information
comes from. The following sections explain how to redirect standard input
to a command so it comes from an ordinary file instead of from the
keyboard.

You can cause the shell to redirect standard input or standard output of
any command by associating the input or output with a command or file
other than the device file representing the keyboard or the
terminal(screen).

The **cat** utility provides a good example of the way the keyboard and
terminal(screen) function as standard input and standard output,
respectively. When you run cat, it copies a file to standard output.
Because the shell directs standard output to the screen, cat displays the
file on the screen.

**cat** writes to the standard output, which is not necessarily a
terminal,
even if cat was typed as part of a command to an interactive shell. If
you really need something to write to the terminal even when the standard
output is redirected, that is not so easy (you need to specify which
terminal, and there might not even be one if the command is executed from
a script)

Answer (score 0):

You can just read from `stdin`, as @MikeCAT says, but as a beginner you may not know how to do that. You can use `getchar`, `fgets`, and `scanf`, to name a few. There is no need to "open" `stdin`, because it is opened by default for any C program, as are `stdout` and `stderr`. If you are running on Linux, you can learn about the usage of the various input functions by using `man`... i.e., `man getchar`. If you're not on Linux, you can just do a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=fgets).

Comment: the function `gets()` was removed from the C language several years ago.  Your compiler should warn you about this if you use it in a program.  I.E. do not be recommending the use of `gets()`

Comment: Sorry, @user3629249, you are right. I use these so rarely myself that I forgot. I will change my answer.